# Jenkins blue ocean environment variables

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-blueocean

I'm using blue ocean for automated testing for every branch created (on every commit). The tests are a little messy right now, so for some tests I need to set an environment variable for an external system. Basically it's an integration test (which shouldn't be there I know, but it is for now). How can I set an environment variable that is apart from setting it in Jenkinsfile. I cannot have it there since it's credentials for another system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set parameterized build  at jenkins configure page like :

> PIPELINE_ID = 123

Then, you can use in `jenkinsfile`:

`${env.PIPELINE_ID}`